# How do I change the project from GCP text to speech python library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am playing with the playing with the gcp python sdk sample (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/texttospeech/snippets/README.rst). I am able to login with gcloud auth login and set the project correctl.

But the library is point to a wrong project ID when I run the sample:

```
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project #841741138139 by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=xxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. [links {
  description: "Google developers console billing"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=xxxx"
```

The above trace is showing I am using the wrong project ID.

I tried to set `GCP_PROJECT` in the env but no use.

How can I set the correct ID in the python client?

Comment: “*The above trace is showing I am using the wrong project ID.*” Actually, it’s not. It shows that billing for the project in question has not been enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the project ID is not the one I enable billing. I have two projects and the one the client is using is invalid.

Comment: Can you share a [mre] of the nonworking code?

Comment: Can you try to set your projectID value in this environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT `?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks a lot! Yes I am missing this env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere in the comments, you need to define the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT` environment variable explicitly  to your python code.

This will ensure that you are pointing to the *projectID* that you want to be used for **Quota and Billing** especially if you have multiple projects.

You may refer to this [Google Auth Library for Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.environment_vars.html) for more information in using environment variables.